# Service methods operating on ManyToMany collection and Law of Demeter

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, collections

I have problem designing service methods operating on @ManyToMany collection in my SpringMVC/Hibernate Rest Web Application without using long method chains that break Law of Demeter. My application has recipes, and inside recipe there is collection of ingredients.

I'm not sure if operations like addIngredientToRecipe() or deleteIngredientFromRecipe() should be inside Recipe class, Ingredient class, or should I create some RecipeIngredientsOperator class ? How to preserve Law of Demeter and avoid chains?

Here is structure of my application:

```
public class Recipe {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Ingredient> ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
}

public class Ingredient {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Recipe> recipeList;
}
```

and service class that I'm having problem with

```
@Service("RecipeService")
public class RecipeServiceImpl implements RecipeService {
    @Autowired
    private RecipeRepository recipeRepository;

    // My approach #1: breaks LoD
    @Override
    public void addIngredientToRecipe(long id, Ingredient ingredient) {
        recipeRepository.findById(id).getIngredients().add(ingredient);
    }

    // My approach #2: looks little better, but still it breaks LoD
    @Override
    public void deleteIngredientFromRecipe(Ingredient ingredient, Recipe recipe) {
        recipe.getIngredients().remove(ingredient);
        recipeRepository.save(recipe);
    }
```

I would be thankful for suggestion what is proper approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a good read....
http://www.yegor256.com/2016/07/18/law-of-demeter.html

I don't mind chaining but I think it more important that the RecipeServiceImpl  not know about the data structures that you are storing the Recipe and Ingredient in.

```
recipe.removeIngredient(ingredient);
```

and

```
recipeRepository.addIngredient(recipeId, ingredient);
```

Comment: What do you think is the proper approach to implement these functions without leaking data structures of recipe and without using `.getIngredients()` in RecipeServiceImpl ? I can't make it in Recipe class, since it is model.

Comment: Could you put it in your RecipeRepository class?

Comment: I think it should be possible through custom SQL statements. I am using using CrudRepository interface in my Repository classes, so I totally forgotten about that option. Thank you!